# Share a local folder over the internet

Tags: networking, 15.10, shared-folders

Good morning,

I have a home server running Ubuntu 15.10 and I would like to share a folder over the internet (not local network) for my colleagues to access. What are the best options? FTP server?

Seb

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do in an easy and quick way, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the directory you want to share, for example: `cd /home/user/Videos`
2. Type the following: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (NOTE: In python3 this changed to `python3 -m http.server`). You should see a message saying `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`, 8000 being the default http port (you can specify it as a parameter in the command at the end)
3. Test your configuration by typing `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser. You should see a list of files in there.
4. Find your IP address (for example, 192.168.1.1) and use that as your external address with the :8000 appended to it.
5. To terminate the server, hit `CTRL+C`.

.

Comment: Also, it's very important to make sure your router redirects port 8000 to your local machine. In other words, 'open' the TCP and UDP ports 8000 in your router for the local machine. Then, find your local IP address on http://icanhazip.com/. You colleagues can now access your directory by navigating to http://<your_ip_here>:8000.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to worry about port forwarding too much, and allow much more options, you can use [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)

This will allow you to share multiple folders, each with different people, with unlimited space. Also, they can add files, if you allow them.

Additionally, it's p2p, so even if your pc is offline, and it's already on another client, the third client will be able to sync. There is also no need for worrying about your dynamic ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python3` then the command is:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

After starting the http server if you want to share the file across internet use **ngrok** https://ngrok.com/  and tunnel it.

Eg ngrok http http://localhost:8000

A link will be generated, use the link to share it over the internet